# How to convert negations and single words with same repetitive letter

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, text-processing

I have a data frame that has a column with text data in it. I want to remove words that mean nothing and convert negations like "isn't" to "is not" from the text data. Because when I remove the punctuations "isn't" becomes "isn t" and when I will remove words having letters less than length 2 "t" will be deleted completely. So, I want to do the following 3 tasks-
1) convert negations like "isn't" to "is not"
2) remove words that mean nothing
3) remove less than length 2 letters
For eg, the df column looks similar to this-

```
user_id     text data column
    1        it's the coldest day
    2        they aren't going
    3        aa
    4        how are you jkhf
    5        v
    6        ps
    7       jkhf
```

The output should be-

```
user_id     text data column
    1        it is the coldest day
    2        they are not going
    3        
    4        how are you 
    5        
    6       
    7
```

How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_repetitive(w):
    """Predicate, true for words like jj or aaaaa."""
    w = str(w)  # caller should have provided a single word as input
    return len(w) > 1 and all((c == w[0]  for c in w[1:]))
```

Feed all words in the corpus to that function,
to accumulate a list of repetitive words.
Then add such words to your list of stop words.

Comment: can you tell me how the syntax of the above function will be if I have to pass the df column to it to find all such words. I get a KeyError: 0 when trying to call this function by passing df column to it

Comment: You might find `df['word_col'].apply(is_repetitive)` to be helpful. Or have another function turn words to "" empty when `is_repetitive()` is True. If you are passing in a sentence, then you'll want a function that splits it to words and discards repetitive words. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Suppose if i have df with 2 columns id and text. The entries in these columns are like 1 aaa, 2 hello aaa, I want the output to be 1 (blank) 2 hello

Comment: If you are passing in a sentence, then you'll want a function that splits it to words and discards repetitive words. Maybe: `return ' '.join([word for word in line.split() if not is_repetitive(word)])`. Or `return ' '.join(filter(is_repetitive, line.split()))`

Answer (score 0):

1) Use SpaCy or NLTK's lemmatization tools to convert strings (though they do other things like convert plural to singular as well - so you may end up needing to write your own code to do this).

2) Use stopwords from NLTK or spacy to remove the obvious stop words. Alternatively, feed them your own list of stop words (their default stop words are things like is, a, the).

3)Use a basic filter, if len<2 remove row

Comment: ....Thanks! what if the df column has words like eeeee, hh, jjjj basically words with same repetitive letter. I want to remove such words. how to do that? And these words could be in combination with a sensible word like hello aaa becomes just hello.